# non-destructive version of pop() for a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

Is there any idiom for getting an arbitrary key, value pair from a dictionary without removing them? (P3K)

EDIT:

Sorry for the confusing wording.

I used the word arbitrary in the sense that I don't care about what I'm getting.

It's different from random, where I do care about what I'm getting (i.e., I need probabilities of each item being chosen to be the same).

And I don't have a key to use; if I did, I'd think it would be in the RTFM category and wouldn't deserve an answer on SO.

EDIT:

Unfortunately in P3K, `.items()` returns a `dict_items` object, unlike Python 2 which returned an iterator:

```
ActivePython 3.1.2.4 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79147, Sep 14 2010, 22:00:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = {1:2}
>>> k,v = next(d.items())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: dict_items object is not an iterator
```

Comment: Do you mean a non-destructive version of `.popitem()`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'arbitrary'? Will you do it more than once, and if so, should it be different each time?

Comment: I may do it more than once; but I'm perfectly fine getting the same value or a different value.

Comment: In Py2 dict.items() returns a list of two-tuples (key, value). dict.iteritems() returns an iterator of such. In Py3 dict.items() returns a dict view object, and dict.iteritems() is gone.

Comment: So `next(iter(d.items()))` would be best then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to access arbitrary element from dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593651/pythonic-way-to-access-arbitrary-element-from-dictionary)

Comment: @TheEspinosa I asked it 2 years earlier and about python 3 rather than python 2. But yeah, they are the same questions.

Comment: Actually your question could stand on its own because of the python 3 aspect. But the answers to your question were mostly for python 2 and/or low quality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
k, v = next(iter(d.items())) # updated for Python 3
```

Comment: 2.x users (eg. just about everyone except the OP), be sure to use `iteritems`.

Comment: @Glenn - exactly. First I wrote it with `iteritems()`, then I saw this P3K and had to think about what's new in P3K.

Comment: Thanks... I started learning Python, and assumed I should choose the latest version.. :)

Comment: Oh man, it doesn't work :( see my edit to the question. So I suppose I have to use `k, v = next(iter(d.items()))`

Comment: After a couple of days of upvoting this, I forgot the syntax. So basically my version of this is or would be something like:
`[ x for x in d.values()][0]`

Answer (score -1):

pop is supposed to remove a item. Isn't that the meaning of that method?

If you want to get random key , value pair use pseudo random module

```
>>> import random
>>> x = {1:3, 4:5, 6:7}
>>> x = {1:3, 4:5, 6:7, 'a':9, 'z':'x'}
>>> k = random.choice(x.keys())
>>> x[k]
7
>>>
```

Comment: See @Glenn Maynard's comment on AndrewBC's answer.

Answer (score -1):

The `items()` method returns the copy of key, value pairs of dictionary as list. For example, 
`>fruits_color = {'apple': 'red', 'banana': 'green'}

>fruits_color.items()

[('apple', 'red'), ('banana', 'green')]`

Once you have the list you can pick the key-value pairs.

Answer (score -2):

```
import random
k, v = random.choice(d.items())
```

Comment: "Arbitrary" does not mean "random"; there's no reason for any randomization here.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard.  How do you know that?  Getting an "arbitrary" item is what `get()` or `[]` does.  If that trivial, obvious use of `get()` isn't the right answer, then there must be some mysterious other forces at work.  Like randomness.

Comment: `get` and `[]` retrieve a *specific* item, not an arbitrary one, and are irrelevant because you have to know a key in advance to use them.  (Is he really asking me how I know what the word "arbitrary" means?)

Comment: @Glenn Maynard. OP probably did not mean choosing randomly, but it's simply the difference between getting an arbitrary something, and getting a something arbitrarily. It could be a valid inference to make, but it probably is not in this case.

Comment: On py3k you need `list(d.items())`

Answer (score -3):

Get a "arbitrary" key-vaue pair?

```
k, v = k, d[k]
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't have `k` at my disposal. So I need something that gives me `k` and `v` from just a dictionary.