# Pythonic way to access arbitrary element from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, full of items. I want to peek at a single, arbitrary item:

```
print("Amongst our dictionary's items are such diverse elements as: %s" % arb(dictionary))
```

I don't care which item. It doesn't need to be *random*.

I can think of many ways of implementing this, but they all seem wasteful. I am wondering if any are preferred idioms in Python, or (even better) if I am missing one.

```
def arb(dictionary):
# Creates an entire list in memory. Could take a while.
    return list(dictionary.values())[0]

def arb(dictionary):
# Creates an entire iterator. An improvement.
    for item in dictionary.values():
        return item

def arb(dictionary):
# No iterator, but writes to the dictionary! Twice!
    key, value = dictionary.popitem()
    dictionary[key] = value
    return value
```

I'm in a position where the performance isn't critical enough that this matters (yet), so I can be accused of premature optimization, but I am trying to improve my Python coding style, so if there is an easily understood variant, it would be good to adopt it.

Comment: What about `dictionary.itervalues().next()`? That would at least be better than your second `arb` function.

Comment: @sgerg I was going to submit that but you go ahead. :D

Comment: Do they need to be different items across call? All these will return the same item...

Comment: @srgerg: except you should do `next(dictionary.itervalues())`; this is the recommended style and has some benefits (no change for Python 3 compatibility - where the `next` method becomes `__next__` - and the possibility of a default value).

Comment: @carrot-top: There is no requirement for that.

Comment: Not doing extra work when you know you don't need to isn't premature optimisation. It's efficiency.

Comment: if you want to peek an _item_ (in contrast to a value) you should use `iteritems` not `itervalues` /nitpick/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Similar to your second solution, but slightly more obvious, in my opinion:

```
return next(iter(dictionary.values()))
```

This works in python 2 as well as in python 3, but in python 2 it's more efficient to do it like this:

```
return next(dictionary.itervalues())
```

Comment: A lot more obvious in my opinion!

Comment: It should be noted that this raises StopIteration if the dict is empty.

Comment: But if you wanted to avoid the `StopIteration`, you could specify a default value, e.g. `next(dictionary.itervalues(), None)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I see it as "a lot more obvious", but definite points for fitting in a single expression.

Comment: @Oddthinking: it depends on how familiar you are with these aspects of Python. For someone who *is* familiar with it, this solution *will* be more obvious than creating a whole `for`-loop. For one who is not, it won't be. Manual iteration is a very handy thing to learn about.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I understand manual iteration, and have used it when required, but I am quick to return to for-loops as soon as I can. Since Python 2.2's ability to use generators as iterators, manual iteration will always be more esoteric than for-loops. That said, if this is the recommended style and is widely understood, I will be quick to adopt it.

Comment: @Oddthinking: if you *are* just wanting a single element from an iterator, `next` is the way to go. No point in `for a in b: return c` or having an unconditional `break` statement in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: I've updated your answer for the modern python 3 times, because this is still a popular question. If you're unhappy with the changes I made, feel free to rollback or edit to your liking.

Comment: How could you get a second or third arbitrary item/value?

Comment: Just keep calling `next`.

Answer (score 11):

Avoiding the whole `values`/`itervalues`/`viewvalues` mess, this works equally well in Python2 or Python3

```
dictionary[next(iter(dictionary))]
```

alternatively if you prefer generator expressions

```
next(dictionary[x] for x in dictionary)
```

Comment: you could simply also do `next(iter(dictionary.values()))`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, but in python2, that creates an extra list.

Comment: `map` also creates a list in Python 2.

Comment: @user2357112, ah yes you are correct. I'll delete that one, since some people are still trying to support 2 and 3

Answer (score 3):

I believe the question has been significantly answered but hopefully this comparison will shed some light on the clean code vs time trade off:

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import choice
A = {x:[y for y in range(100)] for x in range(1000)}
def test_pop():
    k, v= A.popitem()
    A[k] = v

def test_iter(): k = next(A.iterkeys())

def test_list(): k = choice(A.keys())

def test_insert(): A[0] = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('pop', timeit("test_pop()", setup="from __main__ import test_pop", number=10000))
    print('iter', timeit("test_iter()", setup="from __main__ import test_iter", number=10000))
    print('list', timeit("test_list()", setup="from __main__ import test_list", number=10000))
    print('insert', timeit("test_insert()", setup="from __main__ import test_insert", number=10000))
```

Here are the results:

```
('pop', 0.0021750926971435547)
('iter', 0.002003908157348633)
('list', 0.047267913818359375)
('insert', 0.0010859966278076172)
```

It seems that using iterkeys is only marginal faster then poping an item and re-inserting but 10x's faster then creating the list and choosing a random object from it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `random`?

```
import random

def arb(dictionary):
    return random.choice(dictionary.values())
```

This makes it very clear that the result is meant to be purely arbitrary and not an implementation side-effect. Until performance becomes an actual issue, always go with clarity over speed.

It's a shame that dict_values don't support indexing, it'd be nice to be able to pass in the value view instead.

Update: since everyone is so obsessed with performance, the above function takes <120ms to return a random value from a dict of 1 million items. Relying on clear code is not the amazing performance hit it's being made out to be.

Comment: Where it has been specified that the selected element doesn't need to be random, this is a waste of time. A docstring (and the name!) is wholly sufficient for such observations.

Comment: If the name is 'arbitrary' and the action is to iterate through the keys, that name wouldn't be clear to me, so yes, a docstring is necessary. If you have to write a docstring to explain why your code is doing something other than it appears, maybe the answer is to write clearer code.

Comment: 120 ms is utterly unacceptable for an operation like this. This should finish in under a microsecond. You put this in where you were previously using `d[next(iter(d))]` and your application could get literally a million times slower.

Comment: In modern Python you'll get: `TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`. This works instead: `random.choice(list(dictionary.values()))` But this is handy in that you can sample different arbitrary elements.