# Finding the type of dictionary values without knowing the keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let us assume we have a dictionary like so:

```
my_dict = {'foo': [1, 2.325, 'asdasd', lambda x: x[0], ...], ...}
```

How can one get the type of the values (the individual items in the list, and not the list itself) without knowing any of the keys in the most efficient way?

I came up with two approaches but they both feel like an overkill:

> Approach 1:

```
var_types = [type(x) for x in list(my_dict.values())[0]]
```

I imagine that as the dictionary gets big, casting the `my_dict.values()` to list might get slow..

---

> Approach 2:

```
for k in my_dict:
    var_types = [type(x) for x in my_dict[k]]
    break
```

An entire `for` loop that is manually terminated after a single iteration..

So, is there a better way?

The problem is that `dict.values()` does not return an *iterator* but a *dict_values* object which does not support indexing..

**EDIT: For this example it is safe to assume that the variable types across all dictionary keys are the same.**

Comment: `dict_values` does implement the iterator protocol. Just because it doesn't support indexing doesn't mean it isn't iterable.

Comment: @NicholasFlees So how would you do it?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do. Are you just trying to get the type of the first element of the values in the dictionary (which are assumed to be lists)?

Comment: @NicholasFlees I am trying to get the `[type(x) for x in my_list]` if `my_list` is the value of an arbitrary dictionary key. So in this example it would be `[int, float, str, function, ..]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `next(iter(my_dict))` to select an [arbitrary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593651/pythonic-way-to-access-arbitrary-element-from-dictionary) and then derive the types via `map()` or a comprehension:

```
list(map(type,my_dict[next(iter(my_dict))]))

[type(item) for item in my_dict[next(iter(my_dict))]]
```

Comment: `iter` is nice! But you can also use it directly on the values. Like `next(iter(my_dict.values()))`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis That's true and better for Python 3. For Python 2, you would want `.itervalues()` instead of `.values()` to avoid creating a list copy. The syntax I use doesn't require any modifications for Python 2, but since you've tagged Python 3, go with your way :)